# non-native OpenCV library package was not found error while attempting to run OpenCV on android, after downloading OpenCV Manager

Tags: java, android, opencv

Basically my problem is, after setting up my dev environment to work on openCV applications, when I actually run the application I was prompted to download the openCV Manager. Directly after I get another package that says:

"Package not found" 
"OpenCV library package was not found! Try to install it?"

I click yes and it takes me to a place that does not exist on the google play store.

Here are the screenshots that I took while dealing with this from my phone:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pCii.jpg

Ive been searching, and trying to fix this for a few hours now and I am completely lost on what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the link to the [OpenCV Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine&hl=en). You could also use OpenCV without the manager by static initialization.

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        // Handle initialization error
}
```

More details are in this [link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue after installing the OpenCV Manager from the App Store (for GS Note 4). I fixed it by installing the apk file packaged with the OpenCV for Android SDK.

```
OpenCV-2.4.XX-android-sdk
|_ apk
|   |_ OpenCV_2.4.XX_binary_pack_armv7a.apk
|   |_ **OpenCV_2.4.XX_Manager_2.20_XXX.apk** <<
|
|_ doc
|_ samples
|_ sdk
|_ LICENSE
|_ README.android
```

See [How To Chose OpenCV Manager](http://docs.opencv.org/platforms/android/service/doc/UseCases.html#manager-selection")